# Flask and heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I have developed a flask app and intending to deploy it on Heroku but I have been facing problems. the API works fine on postman and localhost but when I deploy it the application crashes with an error code of H10.any suggestions plz?

the API is on OpenCV TensorFlow-CPU (coz Heroku doesn't support GPU I guess) Keras and dlib.
LIST of my requirements:

```
absl-py==0.11.0
astunparse==1.6.3
cached-property==1.5.2
cachetools==4.2.1
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
flatbuffers==1.12
gast==0.3.3
google-auth==1.27.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.2
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.32.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata==3.4.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
Keras==2.4.3
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
Markdown==3.3.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.19.5
oauthlib==3.1.0
opencv-python==4.5.1.48
opt-einsum==3.3.0
protobuf==3.15.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.7.1
scipy==1.5.4
six==1.15.0
tensorboard==2.4.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
tensorflow-cpu==2.4.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.4.0
termcolor==1.1.0
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.26.3
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some compatibility issues with some dependencies in heroku and you can try downgrading a few depending on the error message you get. When I tried with you
requirement list I got :-

```
remote:        Successfully built termcolor wrapt
remote:        ERROR: tensorflow-cpu 2.4.1 has requirement wheel~=0.35, but you'll 
have wheel 0.34.2 which is incompatible.
remote:        Installing collected packages: six, absl-py, astunparse, cached- 
property, cachetools, certifi, chardet, click, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, MarkupSafe, 
Jinja2, Flask, flatbuffers, gast, pyasn1, rsa, pyasn1-modules, google-auth, oauthlib, 
idna, urllib3, requests, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, google-pasta, 
grpcio, gunicorn, numpy, h5py, typing-extensions, zipp, importlib-metadata, PyYAML, 
scipy, Keras, Keras-Preprocessing, Markdown, opencv-python, opt-einsum, protobuf, 
tensorboard-plugin-wit, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, termcolor, wrapt, 
tensorflow-cpu
```

in heroku cli logs (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)

when I tried changed it to tensorflow-cpu 2.4.0 then it worked but it also depends whether you application will run after changing then it works but your application might not work so you will have to modify versions of dependencies to check if it is compatible with both heroku and your doesnt affect the working of your applications.

References :

https://github.com/Anirudh-thakur/FlaskNoteDetector#how-to-deploy-on-heroku-

https://flassger-banknote.herokuapp.com/apidocs/

Comment: thanks a lot! so you mean to say that certain versions of the requirements work on Heroku-20 right? yeah, I have noticed so. so hey if possible can I know the specific versions that worked with you....like if u did a project deployed on Heroku where Opencv, Keras, TensorFlow is involved I would love to know the exact req.txt set which worked flawlessly. cheers and thanx! and also I would like to check out your project as mentioned in references., could I know the endpoints please? cheers and thanx <3

Comment: No issues, actually this project that I shared is the closest what I have worked with a machine learning model(Random Forest) This is the file that worked for me [requirement file](https://github.com/Anirudh-thakur/FlaskNoteDetector/blob/main/requirements.txt) and these are the endpoints [get request](https://flassger-banknote.herokuapp.com/predict?variance=1&skewness=2&curtosis=3&entropy=4) , [post request](https://flassger-banknote.herokuapp.com/predict_file) with file in the body.